# Continuously update multiple widgets

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to implement simple *download manager* to my app. I have files:

**downloader.dart**:

```
List<downloader> downloads = new List<downloader>(); // Used as global variable, to store different downloads.

class downloader{
  double progress;

  void download() async{
    await dio.download(url, path, onProgress: (received, total) { //dio is library to download files
      progress = (received / total).toDouble();
    });
  }

  Stream<double> getStream() async* {
    yield progress;
  }
}
```

**downloadmanager.dart**:

```
import 'package:appname/downloader.dart' as d; 
//DEFAULT STATEFUL WIDGET STUFF
class DownloadManager extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DownloadManagerState createState() => _DownloadManagerState();
}

class _DownloadManagerState extends State<DownloadManager> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Download Manager")),
      body:
        new StreamBuilder(
            stream: d.downloads[0].getStream(), //Hardcoded first element of the array, for testing purproses.
            initialData: 0,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<double> snapshot) {
          return new Text(snapshot.data.toString());
        })
    );
  }
}
```

When I load the `DownloadManager` StatefulWidget it shows the progress of the download when it was loaded, but doesn't update. How to make the `DownloadManager` show current progress and update?

Note: When the `DownloadManager` is loaded, the `downloads` list already has elements, and the `download()` function is in progress/finished.

Thanks.

Comment: use `StreamBuilder` and `StreamController` and remove that `Stream<double> getStream() async* {` method

Comment: sure, youre welcome